# Test method call in the constructor

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have the following code

```
class SomeClass

  def initialize(opts)
    if opts[:should_load]
      load
    else
      setup(opts[:path])
    end
  end

  def load; end

  def setup; end
end
```

And I want to test that the appropriate method is being called, but I cannot figure out how to do this with RSpec. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play with `Object#any_instance` (rspec >= 2.6.0):

```
SomeClass.any_instance.should_receive(:load)
SomeClass.new(:should_load => true)

SomeClass.any_instance.should_receive(:setup).with("mypath")
SomeClass.new(:path => "mypath")
```

Comment: I am using RSpec 2.6.0, however I am getting 'private method pretty_print called for RSpec'. Google has no information on this error, have you encountered it before?

Comment: @providence: sorry, answer edited, obviously an object instantiation returns the object itself. So now I only check that the call is made.

Comment: providence, I am getting the pretty_print error for something completely unrelated to this, did you find a resolution?